# Java mouseDragged logic

Tags: java, image, mouse, drag

I have an image loaded (imagePanel) which has a mouseListener added to it earlier in the class.

The ImagePanel is being dragged around, but only by the upper left-hand corner of the image(0,0). the logic below is my attempt at offsetting the mouse coordinate but it appears to have no effect, I believe it could be that mousePressed() isn't being called.

```
class MouseMotionHandler extends MouseMotionAdapter implements MouseListener
{
    int diffX, diffY;


    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        diffX = e.getX() - imagePanel.getImageX();
        diffY = e.getY() - imagePanel.getImageY();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
    {                           
        imagePanel.setX(e.getX()-diffX);
        imagePanel.setY(e.getY()-diffY);
        imagePanel.repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Any help would be great.

EDIT: SOLVED

The problem was where I initialized the listeners.
mousePressed() is part of the MouseListener class and mouseDragged() is part of the MouseMotionListener class. so I needed to add seperate listeners for each:

```
MouseMotionHandler mouseMotionHandler = new MouseMotionHandler();
imagePanel.addMouseListener(mouseMotionHandler);
imagePanel.addMouseMotionListener(mouseMotionHandler);
```

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: a simple way to test if event listeners are working, is to add some print statements.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that, and yes mousePressed() is not being called any idea why?

Comment: Maybe you didnt add you mouse motion handler to the component you thought you did?

Comment: I added it to the imagePanel which displays my BufferedImage object.

imagePanel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionHandler());

Comment: Can you show how you added it? Not sure if it helps, but I added an example below.

Comment: One thing it could be (I could be wrong its been a long time since I have played around with swing), is that maybe the component you added over your imagePanel isnt inheriting the mouseListener. I dont remember how that is dealt with, but a simple test would be to just display your panel that you are placing your buggeredImage object on without the image. Also, sometimes it helps to change the colors of panals to make sure they are sitting where you think they are.

Comment: Thanks for your help John, I have edited the original post with how I solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html), it gives an example of using a mouse-motion listener.

Comment: I looked at this before but now I see the problem.

The problem was where I initialized the listeners.
mousePressed() is part of the MouseListener class and mouseDragged() is part of the MouseMotionListener class. so I needed to add seperate listeners for each

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to use [Transfer Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html)?
I have used it with success

**Example for JTable**

```
tbItens.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler(){

    @Override
     protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c)
     {
         JTable table= (JTable)c;
         int row = table.getSelectedRow();
         return new StringSelection(String.valueOf(row));
     }

    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c)
    {
        return TransferHandler.COPY;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support)
    {
        if(!support.isDrop())
            return false;

        if (!support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor))
                return false;

        boolean copySupported = (COPY & support.getSourceDropActions()) == COPY;
            if (copySupported) {
                support.setDropAction(COPY);
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support)
    {
        if(!this.canImport(support))
            return false;
        JTable.DropLocation dl = (JTable.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();
        int row = dl.getRow();


        String data;
        try
        {
            data = (String)support.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }


        if(data == null || data.isEmpty())
            return false;

        //row = para onde vai
        //i Ã© aonde estava
        int i = Integer.valueOf(data);

        ArrayList<Object> lo = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for(int k=0; k< tbItens.getRowCount(); k++)
        {
            Object v = tbItens.getValueAt(k, 0);
            lo.add(v);
        }
        DefaultTableModel dt = (DefaultTableModel) tbItens.getModel();
        while(dt.getRowCount() != 0)
            dt.removeRow(0);

        Object item = lo.remove((int)i);
        lo.add(row, item);

        for(Object o : lo)
            dt.addRow(new Object[]{o});
        return true;
    }

});
```

Comment: That seems a lot less elegant

Comment: maybe not....it is actually in the documentation, see:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html